# Calculate checksum digit for a barcode of type Code128

Tags: c#, barcode, code128

I have to calculate a checksum digit for a barcode of type Code128 in C#, similar to this post: https://support.idautomation.com/Code-128/Manually-calculate-check-digit-for-Code-128/_1025

I read this page which gives some calculation examples: https://www.barcodefaq.com/1d/code-128/#CalculationExamples

It states the basic steps of the algorithm:

- Reference the character set table to obtain the value of the start character and all data characters.
- Assign a weight to each data character (not the start character, just the data characters.) The weighting starts at 1 and increases by one for each data character.
- Multiply the character values by their weights for the data characters.
- Add these together including the start character, divide by 103 and obtain the remainder.
- Use the character set table to locate the character that has the value of the remainder, use this as the check character.

I understood this description in general, but I am not sure how to implement the part "Reference the character set table to obtain the value of ... the character"

May question is: How can a write code that gets a value for a certain character depending on whether I want the checksum according to version / codeset A, B or C of the Code128 character set?
https://www.barcodefaq.com/1d/code-128/#Code-128CharacterSet

Do I have to re-create the table with the character set in code (as a big dictionary?) or can I just perform some easy calculation to get the value for a character for Code128 version / CodeSet A, B, or c?

How should I implement this methods?

```
private uint GetValueForCode128Character_CodeSetA(char character)
{
}

private uint GetValueForCode128Character_CodeSetB(char character)
{
}


private uint GetValueForCode128Character_CodeSetC(char character)
{
}
```

I also read the answer to this question: [Is this code for calculating Code128 barcode check digits correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728719/is-this-code-for-calculating-code128-barcode-check-digits-correct)

But that seems to refer to the algorithm in general (which I understand) and less on getting that value for certain character depending on the Code128 codeset A,B or A.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You always need to use [the table on this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128) for each one of the Code 128 variants (A, B, C).

Code 128A's start character has a value of 103, Code 128B's start character has a value of 104, and Code 128C's start character has a value of 105. All of the checksum calculations are performed independently of whether the barcode is Code 128 A, B, or C. There is no further contribution to the value of the checksum, other than the value of each variant's start character.